# grocery crud get relation table fields

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2, grocery-crud

I have a problem with grocery CRUD and "set_relation_n_n" function:
http://www.grocerycrud.com/documentation/options_functions/set_relation_n_n

I want the fields from "This Table", "Relation Table" and "Selection Table". There are any way to do that?. This is my schema (MySQL):
[image: my tables]

**EDITED:**

A few things (by the moment):

This table: timeline_events;

Relation table: timeline_events_options;

Selection table: timeline_events_tags;

`id_timeline` is the foreign key from another table (not showing in the image above), `event_id` is a field required for the widget I am using now. `id_event` is the foreign key from `timeline_events`, `id_event_tags` is the foreign key from `timeline_events_tag`s.

Thank you very much for your answers :).

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should repair your tables first. All three tables has primary key named id which could be `id_timeline` in `timeline_events` table; `id_event` in `timeline_events_options` table and `id_tag` in `timeline_events_tags` table. Considering this as your table fields, this should be the function.

```
$crud->set_relation_n_n('eventtags', 'timeline_events_options', 'timeline_events_tags', 'id_timeline', 'id_tag', 'tags','priority');
```

I don't guaranty it will work because I didn't test it but you can try this one.

Comment: No, didn't work (database error). I edited my post for a few clarifications :). Thank you very much for your answer.